# Is there virtual LEGO designing software?

Tags: software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do any programs exist that allow you to build own LEGO plans?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12/do-any-programs-exist-that-allow-you-to-build-own-lego-plans)

Some years ago, there was a really good program to build models from LEGO. But today I can't find it. Do you know such software which runs on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LEGO Digital Designer](http://ldd.lego.com/download/default.aspx) that was the client/creation part of **Design**By**Me** is Windows or Mac only.

This is regularly updated with the latest sets of parts available through Pick a Brick and similar tools.

It allows you to print off building instructions, or [upload your creations to the LEGO site](http://ldd.lego.com/en-us/gallery/).

Previously, you were able to order a boxed set of your model for yourself, friends or family, however The LEGO Group discontinued this service in January 2012.