# How do I create manuals in the same style as LEGO instruction manuals?

Tags: tools, instructions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do any programs exist that allow you to build your own LEGO manuals?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12/do-any-programs-exist-that-allow-you-to-build-your-own-lego-manuals)

I want to create my own manuals, but I want them to look and feel like actual LEGO instruction manuals. So, I probably need a style guide and / or tool that helps me to achieve this. Are these tools and style guides available?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not clear about my question. :) I'm not asking for actual building tools, but for style guides. I'll update my question.

Comment: Ah, would you be talking about getting the right type of paper and printing and assembling it? If so, then this is certainly not a duplicate. :)

Comment: That's what I meant. Sorry about the confusion. :)

Comment: This was clarified not to be a duplicate after several people voted; unfortunately there is no way to rescind close votes. (On the other hand, an answer was accepted that doesn't jive with the clarification. So I have no idea, really.)

Comment: I thought there was a way to vote to reopen a question. Is there? Cause I'm not seeing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The online consensus on this question seems to be using [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org/), and progressively create the model while saving the steps (like [this tutorial explains](http://www.lkmachines.com/Tutorialinstructions.php)).

However, I remember an other way, but I can't put .. oh wait, it was using [MLCad](http://www.holly-wood.it/mlcad/basic1-en.html).

Answer (score 2):

[LPub](http://www.ldraw.org/Downloads-req-viewdownloaddetails-lid-18.html) is a program designed specifically to produce step-by-step construction documentation from LDraw files. I haven't tried it myself (<strike>it's Windows-only</strike>) but I believe most of the fan-created instructions out there are made with it.

Edit: As Retracile [notes in his answer to a similar question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/471/99) there is a newer version, LPub 4, which also supports Mac.