# Is there a way to draw LEGO figures using Blender?

Tags: software, cad

I have some *basic* experience in [Blender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29). Is there any way to insert pre-drawn LEGO pieces into Blender?

Comment: Will it blend, in other words?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First note that this question is a possible duplicate of [Do any programs exist that allow you to build your own LEGO manuals?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12/do-any-programs-exist-that-allow-you-to-build-your-own-lego-manuals)  With that, here is the answer:

1. (optional) Create a model in [LEGO digital designer](http://ldd.lego.com/) or [LDraw](http://ldraw.org/) and export it as a LDraw (*.ldr) file.
2. Install [LeoCAD](http://leocad.org/trac), and either open the model that you made in LDD/LDraw (recommended) or create your model directly in LeoCAD.
3. Export your model in LeoCAD as a 3D studio (*.3ds) file and import that in Bender.

I learned this technique from this very site less than a week ago and have already tried it out.  So far, it works great and has given me loads of ideas.

Edit: The Linux version of LeoCAD currently does not export to the *.3ds file format, so you can not set up a pipeline that way; I know this from experience.

Comment: You can also use the Lightwave (.obj) exporter from LeoCAD and import that into Blender - note also that LeoCAD has the "Minifig Wizard" allowing you to create your Minifigs directly in there.

Comment: I just did a video using the same method as InkBlend. It worked well for me and here is the link https://youtu.be/kIbvFUuAoLU

Answer (score 2):

For a general introduction to Lego characters (humanoid figures) modeled directly in Blender you might like to view http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWfS82EOa4A&list=EC3F4C5FF0451A92D9 which is a tutorial on modeling a Lego man. I have just begun to analyse this tutorial to see if I can make an expanded PDF version that will incorporate the correct proportions for this figure but when I will complete this task and if I will publish it depends on too many factors to predict.

Answer (score 0):

I would start to model the lego-head.
It is pretty simple, because u can use only one cylinder and then extrude/move and scale faces.

Here is a nice tutorial with an attached blend file.

http://infofreund.de/modelling-lego-head-blender/