# Why is my LDD model incomplete after I export it to LDraw?

Tags: ldraw, ldd

I have an LDD model that I exported to an LDraw file. When I opened it in LDView, only part of it was displayed.

It looks like some parts were not exported properly. Is it normal? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 8):

This in not a LDView problem, but a conversion issue between LDD and LDraw. Only parts present in both libraries will be displayed. Moreover, the file (ldraw.xml) that defines the correspondance between parts of both systems must be up to date. Latest version of this mapping file is available [here](http://gallaghersart.com/page/new_ldd_parts_and_the_ldraw.xml).