# How to import an unofficial parts archive into LDraw?

Tags: ldraw

I recently created a basic EV3 robot in Lego Digital Designer and exported it as a LDraw file. When I opened the LDView file, the EV3 elements were missing. I then proceeded to download an unofficial parts archive from here: http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=85317

The ZIP contains the folders "parts" and "p".  How do I import this into LDraw?

Answer (score 2):

You have no need to use these unofficial parts, all EV3 parts (except for the stickers) are now LDraw official parts, and should already be in your library if it is up to date (otherwise, download and install complete.zip from [here](http://www.ldraw.org/downloads-2/downloads.html)). The problem you most probably have is that the file LDraw.xml that directs conversion between LDD and LDraw doesn't support EV3 parts. For more details on this file, see [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/why-is-my-ldd-model-incomplete-after-i-export-it-to-ldraw/1647#1647).