# How can I control the building instructions generated in LDD?

Tags: instructions, ldd

Is it possible to control the building instructions in LDD?

Specifically, I'd like to make sure that every step stands on its own without falling apart on my build.

If not, is there any software I can use to create customizable building instructions?

Comment: You may want to check out [this answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2087/56) to "Do any programs exist that allow you to build your own LEGO manuals" - it points to [LIC (LEGO Instruction Builder)](https://code.google.com/p/lic/)