# Can I download ldraw instructions from Lego Digital Designer?

Tags: building, design, ldd

Can I download ldraw instructions from Lego Digital Designer?

Is there a collection of simple examples for my youngsters.
I was thinking of: houses, small animals, simple airplane, simple car, tree, ...
Designs with only basic lego bricks.

Can I download them from Digital Designer to create step-by-step instructions with LDraw?

This would help the children a lot in playing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that LEGO Digital Designer can also show you building steps, [but the results have been known to be a little odd](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2087/56).

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here:

**Can I export models from LEGO Digital Designer as LDraw files?**

Yes, although you will probably need to [update the LDraw.xml file](http://gallaghersart.com/page/new_ldd_parts_and_the_ldraw.xml) that LDD uses to export the parts. Once you've completed your model, chose File | Export and set the "Save as type" to (LDraw-Files (*.ldr)" you should then be able to open the file in MLCad, [LEGO Instruction Creator](https://code.google.com/p/lic/) or similar and generate your steps.

**Where can I download simple LDD models from?**

There is LEGO's own [LEGO Digital Designer Gallery](http://ldd.lego.com/en-us/gallery/archive) (currently being upgraded, so this is an archived instance) - each model has a "Download" link under it to download the .lxf. Other locations are probably available as well.