# How do I make instructions from my .ldr/.lxf files on OSX?

Tags: instructions, cad, ldraw, diy

I'm on OSX and I've got a bunch of models made in Lego Digital Designer.  They look awesome!  Now I want to make instructions.

**Q: how do I get from my .ldr files to images or PDF?**
I'll take anything!

There are a couple questions here on stackexchange that are similar, but years have passed and some of the references seem out of date.

From my research I believe (one) workflow is:

- build a model in CAD of choice (I'm using LDD, but there is also LeoCAD)
- import the model into Bricksmith
- in Bricksmith group the parts together to make "steps"
- export the steps from Bricksmith, which makes a .ldr for every step!
- now it's time to render: bring it into LPub
- ... this is where I'm stuck.

The fundamental problem seems to be: LPub is... suboptimal

- LPub needs parts files
- LPub hasn't been updated in a while
- The parts files are generated with Windows-compatible scripts
- the parts files I've used so far just crash LPub

So, is the answer

- "here's how to fix LPub" ?
- Or "Stop using LPub" ?

**Here's what I've found so far:**

- [Making Lego Instructions](http://umlautllama.com/w2/?action=view&page=Making%20Lego%20Instructions) - outlines the workflow I described
- [LDraw parts.lst](http://www.ldraw.org/library/official/parts.lst) - this is the "missing file" that gets generated.  Points to many other files.
- [LDMakeList](http://wiki.ldraw.org/index.php?title=LDMakeList) - the script that generates the list
- [Lego Instruction Creator](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lic/) - stagnant project that was an alternative to LPub.  Has complicated dependencies.

Comment: Update: I'm exploring the print options on LeoCAD, as suggested by [aphink](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6643/what-is-the-easiest-option-to-start-making-instructions).  I'll update here with more details.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://stud.io? It's a Windows and Mac app that works with both ldd and ldr formats based on the LDraw parts library.

Comment: I'm using LPub on Mac since quite a few years. LPub is indeed not updated, but then again, it works... If this is still a question, can you be more specific to what doesn't work? I can try figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

LDD will produce printable instructions on its own.  You can print these into PDF files.  Do you not like the LDD-produced instructions?

Comment: Yes, that is a diplomatic way to put it!  ;)  

Not only can you not design sub-assemblies in LDD, but the piece sequences LDD picks are a bit random -- LDD often picks pieces to "assemble" which aren't connected to anything.  

See the comments [here](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12/do-any-programs-exist-that-allow-you-to-build-your-own-lego-manuals?lq=1) for a particularly egregious example.