# How can I make Custom Instructions for my MOC?

Tags: instructions, customization, moc

I'm a huge AFOL and recently have quit my job in order to take my part time job of selling Lego to the next level.
However, there's a new venture I'm having difficulty with and I would greatly appreciate if anyone has any advice for me...

** I have made a number of custom MOC's and my plan is to create instruction booklet's for the best ones and hopefully sell those online as well. I'm aware that Lego creator is available, however, I'm trying to construct a more tangible set of directions similar to the official Lego instruction booklets you'd receive with one of their sets.

I've seen similar custom directions (without any bricks included) on eBay and so basically I would like to know how that's made possible.

**Are there any businesses or individuals whom have the capability to create such instructions? Any representatives or recommendations you have for me would be great appreciated.

The Lego and AFOL community is amongst the nicest/helpful groups of people I've ever had the pleasure of being involved with, and I'm looking forwards to meeting even more of you this upcoming weekend at The Philly Brick Fest!!!!!!

Comment: I'm assuming you have looked at LDD and LIC from [this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12/do-any-programs-exist-that-allow-you-to-build-your-own-lego-manuals) already? if so, could you specify exactly what you want that those are unable to provide?

Comment: To be honest, I am not very skilled when it comes to using LDD So I was hoping to possibly hire somone whom is much better than I am...also what is LIC? But before I do that, I wanted to see if it was possible to hire someone, send them my completed set, and then they would be able to create an actual Instruction booklet that is not a digital copy but rather an actual, tangeable, Paper instruction booklet much like that you might get from an official Lego set...my buyers have expressed they prefer the paper copy over a digital one.

Comment: If I were you I would change the title of this question to something indicative of your search for someone to do this work for you.

LIC is the [Lego Instruction Creator](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lic/) - it's a tool some people use to make instructions.  I would say it's for "power users" though, so it may not be for you.

Answer (score 3):

- LIC is the Lego Instruction Creator

  - it's a tool some people use to make instructions.
  - I would say it's for "power users" though, so it may not be for you.
- If I were you I might change the title of this question to something indicative of your search for someone to do this work for you.
- As you are probably aware, there are Lego forums which are devoted to MOCs -- so I would solicit for some help there  (Try https://rebrickable.com/forum/ )

Answer (score 1):

Film while you take it apart, then playback in reverse.

Comment: Have you tried this?  How did it work out?  When will you post it on youtube?

Comment: I never tried it myself, but I've seen vids. Looks kinda weird how parts fly into hands.

Answer (score 0):

Google LDraw. It takes some knowledge to use it, but the LPub software that optionally comes with it can make custom instructions.
PS: I personaly recommend using MLCad.

Answer (score 0):

I never made an instruction but to build some MOC's I have used the OpenSource Software Blender to create 3D-Models. There you can create the bricks needed and put them togehter in an easy way and render the images.

Answer (score -3):

Are you still looking for lego instructions? I actually offer a [service for this (through Fiverr)](https://www.fiverr.com/s2/d08e2db77e?utm_source=CopyLink_Mobile), which I feel is quite affordable and rather professional.

Let me know if you are interested! I have 4 years experience with ldd and can help with that too.

Hopefully I can help you with that :)

[image: Sample Instructions]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Bricks! As [per our stance on self-promotion](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) - it would be great if you felt able to register and not use a generic handle :) I believe you've been upfront about your affiliation here, so this shouldn't be considered outright spam.