# Is there a Ubuntu Linux LEGO instruction manual creator?

Tags: software, instructions

Is there a good LEGO instructions manual creator for Ubuntu? I can't seem to find one.

Also, are there any online ones?

Comment: Hi @Redblackva and welcome to Bricks. It would be great if you could add any details of any programs you've already tried, and what didn't work for you so that we can (hopefully) suggest some alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

[LeoCAD](https://www.leocad.org/) is available for Linux based OSs as well as Windows and Mac, and supports Step creation as well as general model creation.

There are a few other workflows detailed in [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/2087/56) to a similar question.

Answer (score 4):

In case you have made your model with LDraw based software with all necessary steps already you can use [LPub3d](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpub3d/files/) to create building instructions. There is a bit of a learning curve to make your instructions look right with required features. But then it makes them look almost like made by LEGO.

There is even an Ubuntu native *.deb package available to download. No need to compile from source.